# Как получить путь к веб-приложению (и только) через ServletRequest (или HttpServletRequest)?

Tags: java, servlet, сервер

Например, у меня есть путь: http://somedomain/someapp/somefile.jsp , а мне нужна только часть http://somedomen/someapp (чтоб потом можно к ней добавить что-то свое для своих нужд и чтоб на любом сервере работало одинаково).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тупо склеил все части:

```
String serverScheme = httpServletRequest.getScheme();
String serverHost = httpServletRequest.getServerName();
int serverPort = httpServletRequest.getServerPort();
String contextPath = httpServletRequest.getContextPath();
String targetBase = serverScheme + "://" + serverHost + ":" + serverPort + contextPath;
```